# Background cell depending of conditional

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have code to color Background of  excel  cell with c# like:

```
 xlAppToExport = new Application();
 xlAppToExport.Workbooks.Add("");
 xlWorkSheetToExport = (Worksheet)xlAppToExport.Sheets[1];

  if (Int32.Parse(task.progress) < 100 && currentDate > task.duedate)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheetToExport.Range["F2", "F5000"].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[2, 6] = task.StatusDescripcion;
                    }
```

As you can see I want to Background color my cell depending of condition. Problem is, all my cells get Background because I use Range["F2", "F5000"].

How can I only colored cells of `task.StatusDescripcion` column where my condition is true? Regards

**Update:**

I change code to

```
xlAppToExport = new Application();
 xlAppToExport.Workbooks.Add("");
 xlWorkSheetToExport = (Worksheet)xlAppToExport.Sheets[1];

  if (Int32.Parse(task.progress) < 100 && currentDate > task.duedate)
                    {

xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[fila, 6].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

      /* I added this to identified what columns get validation, 
     so all columns who have value "Retrasado" equals to validation is true*/
        xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[fila, 6] = "Retrasado";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[2, 6] = task.StatusDescripcion;
                    }
```

So now as you can see in next picture value change to "Retrasado" correctly but column bakgrond get a extrange rule, it paint one and next no and so on, instead paint all who have value of "Retrasado"

[image]